# How to change the direction of the bibliography?

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, lyx

I'm using LyX at Hebrew and JabRef, and this is the result:
[image]

How do I fix it and change the direction of the bibliography from RTL to LTR?

Thank you!

```
% Preview source code

%% LyX 2.3.0 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[a4paper,english,hebrew]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\setlength{\parindent}{0bp}
\usepackage[unicode=true,pdfusetitle,
 bookmarks=true,bookmarksnumbered=false,bookmarksopen=false,
 breaklinks=false,pdfborder={0 0 1},backref=false,colorlinks=false]
 {hyperref}

\makeatletter

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% LyX specific LaTeX commands.
\pdfpageheight\paperheight
\pdfpagewidth\paperwidth


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Textclass specific LaTeX commands.
\usepackage{theorem}
\theorembodyfont{\upshape}
\newtheorem{theorem}{\R{משפט}}[section]
\AtBeginDocument{\make@lr\thetheorem}

% The following chunk fixes export with XeTeX.
% It is needed because polyglossia is used by default
% and \make@lr is only defined by babel.
\@ifundefined{make@lr}
{\def\make@lr#1{\begingroup
    \toks@=\expandafter{#1}%
    \edef\x{\endgroup
  \def\noexpand#1{\noexpand\@number{\the\toks@}}}%
  \x}}{\relax}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{David CLM}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfonttt[Script=Hebrew]{Miriam Mono CLM}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfontsf[Script=Hebrew]{Yehuda CLM}
\AtBeginDocument{
\renewcommand\footnoterule{%
  \kern -3pt
  \hbox to \textwidth{\hfill\vrule height 0.4pt width .4\textwidth}
  \kern 2.6pt
}}

\makeatother

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{hebrew}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\begin{document}
ששש\cite{sep-hume}\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{Eng}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please do not ask the same question more than once... RTL has somehow limited attention (not rare on users) and you have to wait some time (may be a day) but you don't really have more possibilities by asking twice. You may edit your original post to change something if needed

Comment: First of all I'm sorry, but it's different question - I asked at my previous question about both Hebrew and English at the bibliography and here I only asking about English (and change the direction). If it's really same question I'll delete  it. Sorry!! :)

Comment: Don't be sorry... I think the source of the problem is the same and you may edit your first post asking for both... Anyway one answer in this post will answer the previous too, and vice versa... And thus there is no need for both of the questions... I am not sure and I think you may wait before deleting this one... But I suppose that one answer is enough for both questions

Answer (score 0):

[The answer I found:](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/647043/english-bibliography-in-hebrew-document-xetex/649164)
The `bidi` package provides the control sequence `\setLTRbibitems` precisely for this purpose. All you need to do is place this control word before inserting your bibliography.