# English bibliography in Hebrew document (XeTeX)

Tags: xetex, polyglossia, hebrew, bidi

I am writing a Hebrew document all of whose bibliography entries are in English:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{hebrew}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily{\hebrewfont}{DavidLibre-Regular}
\newfontfamily{\englishfont}{Palatino Linotype}
\begin{document}
תרגום לאנגלית של אוקלידס נמצא ב-%
\textenglish{\cite{euclid}}.
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{bib-test}
\end{document}
```

However, the bibliography is printed RTL:
[image: RTL]
To change to LTR I added before the \bibliography command:

```
\selectlanguage{english}
```

This prints the bibliography correctly as LTR but also changes the title to LTR:
[image]
I would like an LTR bibliography with an RTL title.

Comment: It's hardly possible to help without [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that). Although not an expert at multi-language projects, I assume you load and use `polyglossia`. I would try to set the main language as Hebrew and other language(s) as English by adding the following in preamble: `\setmainlanguage{hebrew}`, `\setotherlanguages{english}`. Then, before your bibliography, I'd change the language to English: `\selectlanguage{english}`.

Comment: It's worth noting `polyglossia` also defines macros such as `\text<language>{...}`, dynamically, after `\setotherlanguages{<language>}` has been used. Whatever is inside this macro is typeset according to the `<language>`. In your case that would be `\textenglish{...}`.

Comment: Sorry, Celdor. I have now edited to provide a MWE. In the meantime I have found a workaround (see below), but I'm sure there is some more canonical solution.

Comment: No need to be sorry. It's the same suggestion all over the website and it is for the sake of those who ask questions. You only get the full support and help if you provide enough information. It's impossible without [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that).

Comment: I see. The title of a bibliography is an integral part of the reference list. You could redefine a macro which expands to the desired text, along with alignment, hence: `\renewcommand{\refname}{\raggedleft The New Title}` ([the source](https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=18861)). I would suggest to check `biblatex`. It is definitely more flexible than standard `bibtex`, might work well with `polyglossia` and be better at handling multiple languages.

Comment: For biblatex, does https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/297505/per-language-bibliography-strings-dont-work-for-me-biblatex-biber-polyglossia still apply?

Comment: I don't know. After 40 years of working with BibTeX, I would need a lot of motivation to study the 350-page manual! Since I have a workaround, I'll remain old-fashioned with BibTeX...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `bidi` package provides the control sequence `\setLTRbibitems` precisely for this purpose. All you need to do is placing this control word before inserting your bibliography.

Comment: Thanks, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I still don't have an answer but I have a workaround. First change the class from article to book. Then add the following command to the preamble of the XeLaTeX source file:

```
\gappto\captionsenglish{\def\bibname{\raggedleft\texthebrew{ביבליאוגרפיה}}}
```

The result is what I want:
[image]
A *real* answer would be appreciated.